# Find in dict of dicts based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts:

```
d = {
    "key1" : {"id" : 5},
    "key2" : {"id" : 6},
}
```

What is the most pythonic way of finding some (doesn't matter which) key in this dict that it's value has a specific key / value pair? In my example I would like something like:

```
result = find_by_key(d, "id", 5) # should return "key1"
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of "first key". Considering dicts are not ordered your "first key" could be different every time.

Comment: Define 'first' here; dictionaries have no ordering.

Comment: You are both right, fixing the question.

Comment: @Thimble: well, every time after you mutate the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a generator expression and the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
def find_by_key(d, key, value):
    try:
        return next(k for k, v in d.iteritems() if (key, value) in v.viewitems())
    except StopIteration:
        raise KeyError
```

I assumed you wanted a `KeyError` if no matching dictionary is found.

The generator expression filters the dictionary on values that have the key-value pair, as determined by a membership test against the [dictionary items view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

This does the minimal amount of work to locate a matching key.

Variations:

- In Python 3 `dict.items()` is already a view, and `iteritems()` has been ditched, so use `dict.items()` instead:

  ```
  return next(k for k, v in d.items() if (key, value) in v.items())
  ```
- If you want to return a default instead of raising a key error you can have `next()` return it:

  ```
  def find_by_key(d, key, value):
      return next(
          (k for k, v in d.iteritems() if (key, value) in v.viewitems()),
          None)
  ```

Demo:

```
>>> def find_by_key(d, key, value):
...     try:
...         return next(k for k, v in d.iteritems() if (key, value) in v.viewitems())
...     except StopIteration:
...         raise KeyError
... 
>>> d = {
...     "key1" : {"id" : 5},
...     "key2" : {"id" : 6},
... }
>>> find_by_key(d, "id", 5)
'key1'
>>> find_by_key(d, "id", 6)
'key2'
>>> find_by_key(d, "id", 7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in find_by_key
KeyError
```